# $this->headTitle escapes data

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have my page titles in the database.

For example in my db:

`Brandname&reg; - Home`

Now, if I get this from my db and set the page title with $this->headTitle(), it returns `Brandname&amp;reg; - Home`

Is it possible that this isn't converted? I just want to return what's in the database.
My document is set to UTF8, the view encoding is also set to UTF8. The DB is also in UTF8.

Comment: Try looking into [`htmlentities`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)/[`html_entity_decode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: any feedback would be nice, stack overflow is not only about asking questions to a community, giving them at least a word if you want them to help on your next question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Auto-escaping is turned on by default, you have to call

```
$this->headTitle()->setAutoEscape(false);
```

once somewhere in your code.